# Twitter login page using lwuit

Tags: mobile, java-me, symbian, lwuit

I m developing lwuit symbian application.I need to login via twitter.How can we integrate the twitter login page using lwuit application?symbian

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check TWITTER API ME  libraries. It has support to blackberry & java me as well.

https://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/1.8